# Is there a way to add a security group to an EC2 instance using the CLI like we can with the management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

If I want to quickly add a SG to an instance , is there a way to do it using the CLI like in the management console?

[management console example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeNLx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As security groups are associated with network interfaces actually:

For default: (where only single network interface is available)

> aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id i-123 --groups sg-1
>   sg-2 ..

If an ec2 instance have more than one Network Interfaces ie ENIs you can associate different security groups to different ENIs

> aws ec2 modify-network-interface-attribute --groups sg-1 sg-2
>   --network-interface-id eni-1

source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-attribute.html

Especially the note:

> Note: Using this action to change the security groups associated with
>   an elastic network interface (ENI) attached to an instance in a VPC
>   can result in an error if the instance has more than one ENI. To
>   change the security groups associated with an ENI attached to an
>   instance that has multiple ENIs, we recommend that you use the
>   modify-network-interface-attribute action.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 modify-network-interface-attribute --groups "sg-1234" "sg-12345" --network-interface-id "eni-123456"
```

Re: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-network-interface-attribute.html